# Blank Pygame screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I know that is not really a blank screen, but now I have a problem.
It takes forever to load the game.
Everytime I close the window, it fully loads????
If u need code, ask.

please help

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually placing the sprite on the screen

Comment: If this one is the right indentation,`pygame.quit()` is triggered everytime in the for loop

Comment: @JammyDodger i was for key presses to move it but stackoverflow said I used to much code so i cut it out

Comment: I think you took out too much, since no code here will actually draw your sprite to the screen, the function that draws the text is never called, and the `quit()` function is called every time the loop runs

Comment: @JammyDodger i know here:

Answer (score 2):

You've to crate an `PlayerClass` object and you've to add the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
player = PlayerClass('player_1_0.png', [5, 0])

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)
```

In the main loop you've to updat the position of the player (`player.move()`). Clear the display, draw the sprites and update the display (e.g. by [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update)):

```py
while running:

    # [...]

    player.move()    

    screen.fill([255, 255, 255]) 
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Working example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, sys

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class PlayerClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
    def __init__(self, image_file, speed, location = [0,0]): 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.rect.center = [320, 100] 
        self.speed = speed
        self.angle = 90

    def move(self): 
        global points, score_text
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed) 
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > screen.get_width():
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]  

        if self.rect.top <= 0 : 
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1] 
            points = points + 1 
            score_text = font.render(str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0)) 

player = PlayerClass('player_1_0.png', [5, 0])

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False

    player.move()    

    screen.fill([127, 127, 127])
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```